# Unable to use Flutter_WebRTC package without reload

Tags: android, flutter, webrtc

I am trying to use the [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc), flutter WebRTC. I use it in the following manner:

1. Declare the localRenderer.
2. Initialize it.
3. Call the getUserMedia function to get the stream.
4. Assign the srcObject of localRenderer to the stream.
5. View the local renderer in RTCVideoView widget.

I use 2 and 3 in the initState, and 4 within the getUserMedia.

But, What I am facing is. At first the video does not appear. Until, reload it using `r` while debugging, it suddenly appears.

When in production reloading might not be possible. Is there a way to view the video without reloading everytime?

Answer (score 1):

When assigning the srcObject of the localRenderer to the stream make sure you are doing that inside a `setState`.

The function should look something like this:

```
playVideoFromCamera() async {
    final constraints = {'video': true, 'audio': true};
    final stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
   setState(() {
      _localRenderer.srcObject = stream;
   });
}
```

and wrap things up in the initState

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initRenderers();
    playVideoFromCamera();
  }
```